# Change Tint Image Button after pressed

Tags: android, android-imagebutton, tint

I am trying to create an `ImageButton` able to change the icon color after pressing. I want to do that in my XML file. I have the following code:

```
...

<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/stop_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/stop_icon"
        android:background="@drawable/stop_button"
        android:tint="@color/ship_cove"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_icon_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/start_icon_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/end_icon_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/mediatop_icon_guideline" />
```

And here is my `@drawable/stop_button.xml` file content:

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/cornflower_blue">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/oxford_blue" />
            <corners android:radius="8dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

As I stated before, my purpose is to change my `stop_icon` tint after pressing my `stop_button`, but I do not know how I can do that. **Can anyone help me?**

Note: if my button is not pressed, I want my `stop_icon` with the color `@color/ship_cove`. If it is, I want the color `@color/mirage`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `color` create a color `selector` with a pressed state.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:color="pressed_color" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:color="default_color" />
</selector>
```

And use this `selector` for the color of the icon. The rest should be taken by the system.

Comment: But if I do that, will not I change the entire color of my button? In my case, I want to change only the icon color inside the ImageButton

Comment: Do you mean I need to create another selector to use in my android:tint to change only my icon color?